# TinyMCE Community Version 5: SCRIPT and BR HTML tags being removed

Tags: tinymce

I have SCRIPT and BR listed in extended_valid_elements but those HTML tags are still being removed. I have extended_valid_elements: "script[src|async],br[clear]" I also have allow_script_urls: true

TinyMCE Community Version: 5.0.0-1 (2019-02-04)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine if you use:

```
extended_valid_elements: "script"
```

Here is a working example: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/dyhaab

**EDIT/UPDATE:** If you want to allow attributes on a tag you need to explicitly list them.  The documentation provides a variety of examples (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements)

For your specific case you would want:

```
extended_valid_elements: "script[src]"
```

Here is an updated fiddle:  https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/dyhaab/1

Comment: That example uses a script tag with no attributes. My script tag has a "src" atrribute. If you add a "src" atribute, you'll see that the editor will remove it.

Comment: @user3786746 You just need to update the `extended_valid_elements` to allow that attribute.  See edited answer above.  The documentation provides a full explanation of how this configuration option works.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I alread have this: extended_valid_elements: "script[src|async]"  and it's still being removed.